# Magento - How do i change the size of left sidebar?

Tags: magento, size, sidebar

I am having a little trouble trying to work out how i would reduce the size of the left sidebar and increase the size of the main. i only want this to happen on the main page.

My page is here so you can have a look http://www.theshirt.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full action name - a unique identifier for each route in the system - is added as a class name to the `<body>` tag. Based on this and the template which you are using, the following would make the left column 33px narrower and the main column 33px wider:

```
.cms-index-index .col-left {
    width: 200px;
}

.cms-index-index .col-main {
    width: 761px;
}
```